# C++ xml parser for nmap output

Tags: c++, nmap

I'm new to nmap. I saw in nmap tutorial (https://nmap.org/book/man-output.html) that -oX option can be used to get nmap output in xml format. I want to know if any xml parser written in c++ is available to parse nmap xml output file.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9387610/what-xml-parser-should-i-use-in-c

Comment: Yes there are quite a few libraries that can be used to parse and handle XML. But if you read  ["What topics can I ask about here?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) you will see that asking for that is *off-topic*.

Comment: @jerry is probably asking for an abstraction layer or ORM that would define classes for Nmap constructs like `Host`, `Service`, etc. and create objects from XML input. This is how existing libraries in Python, Perl, Ruby, etc. are written. As an Nmap developer, though, I am not aware of any, so I will be following this question.