# How to install Basex for command line on OS X using Homebrew?

Tags: macos, basex

I'm trying to install BaseX using Homebrew on OS X:

```
$ brew cask install basex
==> We need to make Caskroom for the first time at /opt/homebrew-cask/Caskroom
==> We'll set permissions properly so we won't need sudo in the future
Password:
==> Downloading http://files.basex.org/releases/8.1.1/BaseX811.app.tar.bz2
######################################################################## 100.0%
==> Symlinking App 'BaseX.app' to '/Users/user/Applications/BaseX.app'
  basex staged at '/opt/homebrew-cask/Caskroom/basex/8.1.1' (148 files, 153M)
$ basex
-bash: basex: command not found
```

What exactly needs to be done to run it from command line?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`brew cask` installs GUI applications into `/Applications`, not the command line tools. If you want to install the command line tools, run `brew install basex` (without `cask`).

Also compare the [cask recipy](https://github.com/caskroom/homebrew-cask/blob/master/Casks/basex.rb) installing the application

```
app 'BaseX.app'
```

with the [brew recipy](https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew/blob/master/Library/Formula/basex.rb) installing the command line tools and creating symlinks to the executables

```
libexec.install Dir["*"]
bin.install_symlink Dir["#{libexec}/bin/*"]
```

to get a feeling of the differences.