# Parsing XML elements with attributes in bash script

Tags: bash, xml-parsing

i would like to parse the below xml text in bash script.

```
<os name="RedHat" os_version="6">
<package_manager type="name">rpm</package_manager>
<multipath_package_check type="command">rpm -qa | grep device-mapper-multipath</multipath_package_check>
<mpath_service_enable type="command">chkconfig multipathd on</mpath_service_enable>
<mpath_service_restart type="command">service multipathd restart</mpath_service_restart>
</os>
```

For example, i need to have functions like below to return the text if element attributes match the arguments.

```
get_package_manager "RedHat" "6"
```

should return "rpm"

```
get_multipath_package_check "RedHat" "6"
```

should return "rpm -qa | grep device-mapper-multipath"

appreciate any help.

Comment: Don't try to parse XML using tools like `bash`, `sed` or `awk`. That way lies madness. Use something XML-aware, like `xmlstarlet`.

Answer (score 0):

Some "xml parsing" are easier to do with a flat representation of XML, using the `xml2` (`apt-get install xml2`) program.

Typically:

```
$ xml2 < test.xml | grep package_manager= | cut -d= -f2
rpm

$ xml2 < test.xml | grep multipath_package_check= | cut -d= -f2
rpm -qa | grep device-mapper-multipath
```

But it won't solve anything. For the problem you can't easily solve with `xml2`, you may try expressing your query using xpath and use any xpath tool available in CLI like xmllint:

```
$ xmllint --xpath '/os[@name="RedHat" and @os_version="6"]/package_manager/text()' test.xml
rpm

$ xmllint --xpath '/os[@name="RedHat" and @os_version="6"]/multipath_package_check[@type="command"]/text()' test.xml 
rpm -qa | grep device-mapper-multipath
```

Comment: Awesome, Thank you so much for the answer. This is exactly what i was looking for.

Comment: Any suggestions when "xpath" option is not available with xmllint?. Only latest versions of xmllint seems to have this option.

Comment: @skrish http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15461737/how-to-execute-xpath-one-liners-from-shell