# Shell find a string btween two patterns

Tags: bash, shell, awk, sed

I have a response from a curl command to a text file that looks like this:

`<att id="owner"><val>objs/13///user</val></att><att id="por"><val>objs/8/</val></att><att id="subType"><val>null</val></att><att id="uid"><val>14</val></att><att id="webDavPartialUrl"><val>/Users/user%`

I need to find the string between the string `>objs/8/</val>` and `<att id="uid">`

i have tries awk,sed and grep, but all have issues with special charterers like those above, is there an option to treat the text as simple charterers?

Comment: Perhaps [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15461737/how-to-execute-xpath-one-liners-from-shell) will help?

Answer (score 3):

Using `grep` with `--` (explained [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/11376/what-does-double-dash-mean-also-known-as-bare-double-dash))

```
$ grep -o  -- '>objs/8/</val>.*<att id="uid">' pattern
>objs/8/</val></att><att id="subType"><val>null</val></att><att id="uid">
```

For more specific matching with grep, you can refer to [this question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/13466/can-grep-output-only-specified-groupings-that-match).

Otherwise, because your input seems to be XML, you should consider using an XPATH expression on it. More specifically, it seems that you want to 
retrieve `<att id="subType">`, which should be easy to express.
Adding `<test>` and `</test>` around your sample, I was able to use `xmllint` to retrieve the value.

```
$ xmllint --xpath '/test/att[@id="subType"]' pattern 
<att id="subType"><val>null</val></att>
```

Comment: i tried for testing this:
`al>null</val></att><att id="uid"><val>14</val></att><att id="webDavPartialUrl"><val>/Users/user%" |  grep -o -- '>objs/8/</val>.*<att id="uid">'
`

Comment: however, the response was empty

Comment: although   `grep -o -- '>objs/8/</val>.*'`  does return the string starting from `>objs/8/</val>`

Answer (score 0):

Using Perl:

`perl -ne 'print "$1\n" if m#>objs/8/</val>(.*)<att id="uid">#' file`

output:

`</att><att id="subType"><val>null</val></att>`

Explanation:

- `$1` is the captured string `(.*)`
- `m##` is used here as the matching operator instead of the standard Perl `//`, in order to ignore the special `/` characters