# Extract text between the two anchor tags using sed, grep or awk

Tags: regex, bash, shell, awk, sed

```
<div class="plot_summary minPlotHeightWithPoster">
            <div class="summary_text" itemprop="description">
                    King Leonidas of Sparta and a force of 300 men fight the Persians at Thermopylae in 480 B.C.
            </div>
```

I want to extract the text between the two div anchor tags. I am a newbie to sed and awk and so, I couldn't figure out how to do that. I tried it using grep but it was unsuccessful.

Comment: add the grep command you tried, it will show you had tried something... also, this is best suited for html parser

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Sundeep notes in a comment: **best to use a proper HTML parser**.

The standard utilities are mostly *line*-based and deal poorly with quoting;  they are ill-equipped to robustly parse HTML, with all its variability around quoting styles and whitespace, let alone recognition of the actual syntax.

***GNU* `grep`** offers more flexibility than other implementations: multi-line matching (`-z`), support for PCREs (`-P`), which enables lookaround assertions.

While the following GNU `grep` command works with your sample input, it is still far from being a robust parsing solution:

```
 grep -zPo '<div class="summary_text" itemprop="description">\s*\K.*?(?=\s*</div>)' file
```

Comment: It gave an error,modified it a bit grep -zPo '<div class="summary_text" itemprop="description">\s*\K.*?(?=\s*</div>)' and it worked! Thank you :D

Comment: @SwastikUdupa: Glad to hear it worked; re error: interesting - I don't get one (GNU grep v2.22), but your tweak is the simpler solution anyway, so I've updated the answer with it.

Answer (score 3):

**Recommended method to parse XML or HTML at a Unix or Unix like terminal:**

If you are looking for a way to do this from the unix command line, I suggest first considering an xml parsing tool instead of awk, grep, or sed.

For example your system may have [xmllint](http://xmlsoft.org/xmllint.html). If your html was contained in the file index.html. The following xmllint command works to extract the text:

```
xmllint --html --xpath "//div[contains(@class, 'plot_summary')]/div[contains(@class, 'summary_text')]/text()" index.html
```

The text needs trimming after that command so you'd probably pipe to another command to do that:

```
(xpath="//div[contains(@class, 'plot_summary')]/div[contains(@class, 'summary_text')]/text()" && \
xmllint --html --xpath "$xpath" index.html) \
| sed -e 's/^[[:space:]]*//' -e '/^[[:space:]]*$/d'
```

That sed command we are pipping the output to has two expressions. The first deletes white space at the beginning of the line `'s/^[[:space:]]*//'` and the second deletes any lines that are just white space `'/^[[:space:]]*$/d'`

There are other xml command line parser tools you can research (see accepted answer):
[How to execute XPath one-liners from shell?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15461737/how-to-execute-xpath-one-liners-from-shell)

**Terrible way using sed:**

You can get around the by-line parsing issue of sed by using echo to break your file into one line. Then using an sed replace you can extract the text you want. This is not a good method because it is a very format dependent method:

```
(set -o noglob; echo $(cat index.html)) \
| sed 's/.*<div[^>]*class[^=]*=[^"]*"summary_text"[^>]*>[[:space:]]*\([^<]*\).*/\1/'
```

*Updated to disable [globbing](http://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/globbingref.html) per mklement0's comment via [set command](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/The-Set-Builtin.html)*

Comment: ++ for demonstrating a proper solution. Given that the input is HTML, not XML, you should probably use `xmllint --html`.
The normalize-to-single-line-beforehand approach is probably fine in most cases, except that `echo $(cat ...)` is a bad idea,
because the tokens from the file are subject to _globbing_. A good-enough approximation that avoids this problem is `tr -s '[:space:]' ' '`;
as an alternative to this whitespace normalization step you can loop to build up the entire input within `sed` itself, and in the case of _GNU_ `sed` simply use `-z`.

Comment: Great comment! Lots of learning in there for me. Love it :). I'll update my answer when I'm at a computer and can digest it all. On OSX here. Starting to think I should research getting GNU copies of my favorite commands.  ++ your way too. Cheers @mklement0

Comment: Glad to hear it, and thank you. Yes, life with GNU utilities is much easier, but it's important to be aware what's GNU-specific and what isn't when dealing with other platforms. Addendum to my previous comment: `(set -f; echo $(cat index.html))` is a pragmatic solution to the unwanted globbing problem (note the enclosing subshell to localize the effect of `set -f`).

Comment: Beautiful!  You know I see these types of questions a lot on here. "My sed/grep isn't parsing my HTML properly" questions. Answered a similar one the other day. I've even written solutions in past myself that scraped websites this way. ( that now I would do differently ). Seems like a good thing to add to stack-overflow documentation if it isn't already; Best ways and tools to parse xml, HTML, and JSON from the command line. @mklement0

Comment: I don't see anything like what I suggested in stack overflow documentation. Now a question to ponder and sleep on. Should this topic go under the Bash, Unix, or command-line tag. Has to be one I think. http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/328705/document-belonging-to-multiple-tags-topics. Any thoughts or opinions @mklement0?

Comment: I'd say "command-line" is at least _technically_ the closest match (I couldn't find a "Unix utilities" topic, and "Unix" is awfully broad, and there's nothing Bash-specific about your answer (or mine)) - whether people will actually find it there is another question. While the line between shells and utilities is often blurry, this topic is about _utilities_, not shell(-language) features.