# GitLab-CI get pom version in pipeline

Tags: maven, docker, gitlab, gitlab-ci

I'd like to build docker image via gitlab CI with project's version as a tag:

```
docker build -t dockerimage:VERSION-IN-POM .
```

In jenkins' pipeline i'm getting the version like that:

```
${pom.version}
```

Is it possible to read the version in a similar, convenient way from gitlab CI? Or do I have to write scripts for that?

Comment: I don't believe there is one, however you can write a `before_script` that would `sed` the version from your pom file. In Jenkins there are plugins that can simplify such tasks, however GitLab CI doesn't really have such.

Comment: What was the accepted answer or how did you solve this?

Answer (score 14):

Assuming you have maven in build environment, you could use maven help plugin and grep to extract version.

```
VERSION=$(mvn --non-recursive help:evaluate -Dexpression=project.version | grep -v '\[.*')
echo $VERSION
```

Comment: i had to tail the output, my final statement: VERSION=$(mvn --batch-mode --non-recursive help:evaluate -Dexpression=project.version | grep -v '\[.*' | tail -1)

Comment: Is the backslash in the grep argument really correct? Didn't work for me. See the other comment without backslash now and wonder if the answer is even really wrong. The answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/56311811/1184842 is much more robust anyway I'd say.

Comment: If you use mvn --non-recursive help:evaluate -Dexpression=project.version -q -DforceStdout Then you get the version without all the noisy mvn output. No need to grep!

Answer (score 11):

This work for my variable: `gitlab-ci.yml`

```sh
mvn -Dexec.executable='echo' -Dexec.args='${project.version}' --non-recursive exec:exec -q
```

Answer (score 8):

Gitlab-CI doesn't offer such comforts, instead it offers you to do whatever you want with the shell script. It's not very hard to do it in command script. You can install [xmllint](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4683119/2115135) (`apt install libxml2-utils` on Ubuntu) and then you can get it by a [simple query](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41115011/2115135):

```
xmllint --xpath '/*[local-name()="project"]/*[local-name()="version"]/text()' pom.xml
```

So it can all be solved by these two lines:

```
- apt install libxml2-utils
- docker build -t dockerimage:$(xmllint --xpath '/*[local-name()="project"]/*[local-name()="version"]/text()' pom.xml) .
```

Comment: Not really, what if it inherits the version from a propert file or from a parent?

Answer (score 5):

Another maven command line alternative to get directly get the version information

```
mvn --non-recursive help:evaluate -Dexpression=project.version -q -DforceStdout
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use sed or grep.

It's faster than using `mvn --non-recursive help:evaluate ...`

Get the artifactID

```
grep -m1 '<artifactId>' pom.xml | grep -oP  '(?<=>).*(?=<)'
```

Get the version

```
grep -m1 '<version>' pom.xml | grep -oP  '(?<=>).*(?=<)'
```

If you are using docker, some images don't have newest version of grep, so you need to use come creative solution with cut, example:

```
grep -m1 '<artifactId>' pom.xml |cut -d '<' -f2  |cut -d '>' -f2
```

Comment: "creative cut solution " helped ;) Thanks

Answer (score 3):

You can use the below command in your `.gitlab-ci.yml` file :

```
VERSION=$(mvn --non-recursive help:evaluate -Dexpression=project.version -q -DforceStdout)

echo $VERSION
```

Furthermore you can get `groupId` and `artifactId` by changing  `Dexpression=project.version` to `Dexpression=project.artifactId` and `Dexpression=project.groupId`

For more information see the [maven documentation for help:evaluate](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-help-plugin/evaluate-mojo.html).

Answer (score 1):

As indicated by Ivan in his [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57008986/set-inside-gitlab-ci-yml-a-variable-reading-the-name-of-artifactid-from-pom), this worked in my script:

-RELEASE_VERSION=`xmllint --xpath '/*[local-name()="project"]/*[local-name()="version"]/text()' pom.xml`

-echo $RELEASE_VERSION

Answer (score 1):

if you know the project name, here is another approach using shell; is to cut the version from the target .jar file created under ./target directory.

Note: This will work only after successful build commands:

```
   cd target
   version=`ls <PROJECT_NAME>*.jar`
   version=${version#<PROJECT_NAME>} 
   version=${version%.jar}
   cd ..
   echo $version
```

<PROJECT_NAME> is the name of the project (use without <> marks)

Answer (score 1):

I ended up using

```yaml
vars:
  stage: prepare
  script:
    - echo "POM_VERSION=$(mvn -Dexec.executable='echo' -Dexec.args='${project.version}' --non-recursive exec:exec -q)" > vars.env
    - echo "POM_NAME=$(mvn -Dexec.executable='echo' -Dexec.args='${project.name}' --non-recursive exec:exec -q)" >> vars.env
    - echo "POM_GROUP_ID=$(mvn -Dexec.executable='echo' -Dexec.args='${project.groupId}' --non-recursive exec:exec -q)" >> vars.env
    - echo "POM_ARTIFACT_ID=$(mvn -Dexec.executable='echo' -Dexec.args='${project.artifactId}' --non-recursive exec:exec -q)" >> vars.env
  artifacts:
    reports:
      dotenv: vars.env
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a solution with the Maven help:evaluate but with a regex (see the "-E" in command) :

```
export VERSION=$(mvn --non-recursive help:evaluate -Dexpression=project.version | grep -E '^[0-9]+.[0-9]+.[0-9]+(-[A-Z]+)?$')
echo $VERSION
```

It will be able to find for example **5.0.1-SNAPHOT** or only **5.0.1** or again **5.0.1-GA** in the output of the Maven command.

Tested on this kind of realistic Maven output :

```
Downloaded from fodfin: http://your.server/artifactory/com/thoughtworks/xstream/xstream/1.4.11.1/xstream-1.4.11.1.jar (621 kB at 369 kB/s)
[INFO] No artifact parameter specified, using 'be.test.super.package:the-application:pom:5.0.1-SNAPSHOT' as project.
[INFO]
5.0.1-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD SUCCESS
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time:  15.127 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2022-10-06T14:40:29+02:00
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Answer (score 0):

```
jobname:
  stage: stage
  before_script:
    - export "MAVEN_ID=$(mvn help:evaluate -Dexpression=project.id -q -DforceStdout)"
    - >
      IFS=: read -r MAVEN_GROUPID MAVEN_ARTIFACTID MAVEN_PACKAGING MAVEN_VERSION <<< ${MAVEN_ID}
  script:
    - >
      echo -e "groupId: ${MAVEN_GROUPID}\nartifactId: ${MAVEN_ARTIFACTID}\nversion: ${MAVEN_VERSION}\npackaging: ${MAVEN_PACKAGING}"
```

- `mvn help:evaluate -Dexpression=project.id -q -DforceStdout` prints artifact identification information in the following format: `com.group.id:artifactid:packaging:version`
- `MAVEN_ID` variable is parsed using `IFS` based on the colon (`:`) as a separator to get common maven variables like artifactId, groupId, version and packaging ([explanation](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28225752))
- later these variables can be used in the code, for example for echoing values
- this way maven is executed only 1 time to get the information, which can speed up pipeline
- IFS is a bash feature, thus corresponding GitLab runner should have bash installed