# How to extract an arbitrary tag from a text file and measure the content length in Linux

Tags: linux, shell

I have a text file, the content is made of custom tags :

```
<description>text</description><shortdescription>text for short description</shortdescription>
```

I want to extract in Linux command line the content of , which is "text for short description" and output its length if it is possible.
Thank you.

Comment: Provide the xml node structure from root level? from root node to node having `shortdescription`?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to execute XPath one-liners from shell?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15461737/how-to-execute-xpath-one-liners-from-shell)

Comment: @Inian it is a flat texte file not an xml file

Comment: @YvonHuynh — Why is this question marked as [tag:xml] then? Why are you using an XML-like format instead of actual XML?

Comment: @YvonHuynh: So you want to extract text within `<shortdescription>` tag and its length?

Comment: @Quentin I modified the title of the question

Comment: @YvonHuynh: Why do you have the `xml` tag then?

Comment: @Inian yes, the reason i want to do with shell is because i have potentially 3000 of these files and do not want to do this with a program, I modified the title

Comment: Can you output `grep --version` and see if it is `GNU grep`?

Comment: @Inian the grep version : grep (GNU grep) 2.20

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming your file is a flat file and **NOT** an `XML` you can find the string within the tags using `GNU grep` which supports `perl` style `regEx` match with a the `-P` flag. The flags `-o` and `-m1` are for returning only the matching part and return 1 instance of the match only.

```
grep -oPm1 "(?<=<shortdescription>)[^<]+" input-file
text for short description
```

and for length of the string, store it in a variable the output of above command

```
stringLength="$(grep -oPm1 "(?<=<shortdescription>)[^<]+" file)"
echo "${#stringLength}"
26
```