# What is the difference between namespace and prefix in XML?

Tags: xml, xml-namespaces

I am forced to fight with an external XML and I do not understand what is the difference between namespace and prefix in a XML file. I mean, I am using namespace and name of the label to get a value in this file with Linq library. But I do not know the difference between these.

```
-<a:RoutePointsMeteoData z:Id="31" z:Size="10">
-<b:anyType z:Id="32" i:type="a:WaypointFLMeteoData">
    <a:DevISA>0</a:DevISA>
    <a:DisplayTemperatureType>IsaDev</a:DisplayTemperatureType>
    <a:RelatedRoutePointName>1739276a822f8a919b</a:RelatedRoutePointName>
    <a:TemperatureSource>NotDefined</a:TemperatureSource>
    <a:WindDirection>0</a:WindDirection>
    <a:WindSource>NotDefined</a:WindSource>
    <a:WindSpeed>0</a:WindSpeed>
```

Someone could tell me the main objective of use prefix in labels? For example:

```
<a:DevISA>0</a:DevISA>
```

What could be the purpouse of this a:? Is this a kind of distinctive feature to detect a label?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What does "xmlns" in XML mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1181888/what-does-xmlns-in-xml-mean)

Comment: Do you read the question Joe?

Comment: I did. You're asking for an explanation of XML namespaces and prefixes, and the linked question has a good answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**An XML namespace prefix is an abbreviation for the full XML namespace.**

Because namespaces are meant to differentiate unqualified XML names, it's better that the namespaces themselves be sufficiently long to create a lexically distinct new name when prepended to the unqualified names.  Organizational ownership that's aligned with URI ownership is a nice property that also tends to increase namespace length.

To avoid unwieldy concatenation of a full XML namespace with an unqualified XML name, an abbreviation mechanism was introduced,

```
xmlns:a="http://example.com/some/full/namespace/name"
```

allowing `RoutePointsMeteoData` to be written in this namespace as `a:RoutePointsMeteoData` rather than, say, `{http://example.com/some/full/namespace/name}RoutePointsMeteoData`.  (This alternative notation, known as [Clark Notation](http://www.jclark.com/xml/xmlns.htm), is not standardized – it's not compatible with XML directly, but is commonly used in meta descriptions, parameter names in JAXP API spec, etc)

**Further notes:**

- XML namespace prefixes themselves are arbitrary; it's only through their
  binding to a full XML namespace name that they derive their
  significance.
- XML namespace prefixes ***must*** be declared in order for an XML document to be considered to be [***namespace-well-formed***](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/134494/is-there-any-difference-between-valid-xml-and-well-formed-xml/25830482#25830482).

Comment: The other important point is that *different people can use different prefixes (abbreviations) for the same namespace*. Your `p:foo` can be the same thing as my `q:foo` if your `p` is bound to the same namespace as my `q`.

Comment: @MichaelKay: Right, that follows from the mentioned note about the arbitrariness of the namespace prefixes, but the implication is worth highlighting.  Thank you.