# XPath syntax to edit specific node in HTML using xmlstarlet

Tags: html, linux, xpath, xmlstarlet

Supposing I have an HTML document like what's below:

**mypage.html**

```html
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
  <body>
    <table>
      <tbody>
       ...
       <tr>
         <td id="MY_ID">123</td>
```

How would I edit the element set to `MY_ID`? I've used the following command successfully when it was just the table in a document, but placing it in a larger document broke it:

```
xmlstarlet ed --update '//td[@id="MY_ID"]' --value '456' mypage.html
```

Comment: You say: "placing in a larger document" . Could that larger document be in a namespace? For using namespaces in xmlstarlet, see: https://stackoverflow.com/a/44186555/3710053

Comment: @SiebeJongebloed I've tried using the `/_:` syntax before, and it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `td` element needs to be closed (`</td>`) for it to be valid XML.
You can try the following it [here](http://xpather.com/) :

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
  <body>
    <table>
      <tbody>
       ...
       <tr>
         <td id="MY_ID">123</td>
         <td> id="NOTMYID">127</td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </body>
</html>
```

Using your own expression:
`//td[@id="MY_ID`

Comment: I've fixed the typo in the main post; sorry about that. Testing my expression on that site you reference does show that it's working, so why isn't the value being changed?