# XPath evaluation issue using xmllint

Tags: xml, xpath, xmllint

Given the following xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<tomcat-users>
    <user password="PASSWORD-1"
          roles="manager-script"
          username="manager-script"/>
 <role rolename="manager-gui"/>
<user username="tomcat" password="SECRET" roles="manager-gui"/>
</tomcat-users>
```

I am trying to get the following output string, using the xmllint command: `PASSWORD-1`.

I googled and read quite a lot, and being new to XML parsing, I honestly can't figure it out.

Any idea?

Comment: XPath would be: `/tomcat-users/user/@password`.  I'm unfamiliar with `xmllint` though.  If you only want the first password: `(/tomcat-users/user/@password)[1]`.

Answer (score 0):

The XPath required is: `(/tomcat-users/user/@password)[1]` (i.e. returns the first password attribute of a user in the file.

If you want the password of the first user in the file (subtly different, as there's no guarantee that the first user has a password defined), use `/tomcat-users/user[1]/@password`.

If you want all users' passwords, use `/tomcat-users/user/@password`.

I was unfamiliar with xmllint, so referred to: [How to execute XPath one-liners from shell?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15461737/how-to-execute-xpath-one-liners-from-shell)
The syntax is: `xmllint --xpath '(/tomcat-users/user/@password)[1]' inputFile.xml`

When building an XPath statement, think of it as typing the directory to a file on your file system; you have pieces nested under other pieces, so name the root, then put a slash and name its child, repeating the process until you get to the item you're after.  For attributes, the name should be prefixed with an `@` to show it's an attribute.  Stuff in square brackets is a way of filtering when you may have a "path" which leads to multiple results.  Just putting a number in the square brackets gives you the element at that position (first element is #1; not #0 as in most languages).  There are more advanced things you can do with these filters; but that's going beyond the scope of your question.