# How to search and display value from XML using shell script

Tags: xml, shell

Suppose an XML file spam.xml is like

```
<spam>
<victims>
  <victim>
    <name>The Pope</name>
    <email>pope@vatican.gob.va</email>
    <is_satan>0</is_satan>
  </victim>
  <victim>
    <name>George Bush</name>
    <email>father@nwo.com</email>
    <is_satan>1</is_satan>
  </victim>
  <victim>
    <name>George Bush Jr</name>
    <email>son@nwo.com</email>
    <is_satan>0</is_satan>
  </victim>
</victims>
</spam>
```

How can I find and display the email address of George Bush Jr, from a shell script.

The use of a tool like xmllint or xml2 would be appreciated but not essential.

Edit: I'm sorry, I guess somehow I didn't make the question clear enough.  I know I can run something like

```
$ xmllint --xpath '//spam/victims/victim/name' spam.xml
<name>ThePope</name><name>George Bush</name><name>George Bush Jr</name>
```

but that's not what I am after. I want to search for the name and have returned the email.  Maybe it is not possible, maybe I have to write an extended sed/awk/bash script to do this. I was hoping with all the hype around XML there was a clever and simple way to do it, but maybe not. I am not familiar with XML, that's why I ask :)

Comment: I'd suggest looking here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15461737/how-to-execute-xpath-one-liners-from-shell

Comment: You just need a slightly more complex xpath query. Like `//spam/victims/victim[name='George Bush']/email`

Comment: Awesome! Exactly what I was looking for, thanks!