# Delete before/after lines in xml by matching tag value

Tags: xml, shell, xml-parsing, pom.xml, string-matching

In below XML snipped, I need to delete the unwanted lines matching an artifact ID value:

```
    <groupID>com.test</groupID>
    <artifactID>nginx-node</artifactID>
    <verion>1.0</version>
    <groupID>com.test</groupID>
    <artifactID>nginx-node</artifactID>
    <verion>1.1</version>
    <groupID>com.test</groupID>
    <artifactID>nginx</artifactID>
    <verion>1.2</version>
```

I need to delete all XML lines current, before and after by matching the value of artifact ID ie "nginx-node" in an above XML file

**command tried:**

```
grep -iv "nginx-node" file.
```

**Actual output:**

```
 <groupID>com.test</groupID>
    <verion>1.0</version>
    <groupID>com.test</groupID>
    <verion>1.1</version>
    <groupID>com.test</groupID>
    <artifactID>nginx</artifactID>
    <verion>1.2</version
    **Expected output:**
    <groupID>com.test</groupID>
    <artifactID>nginx</artifactID>
    <verion>1.2</version>
```

Comment: Why don't you use an additional tool like [xpath](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15461737/how-to-execute-xpath-one-liners-from-shell)

Answer (score 0):

This requires a multi-line search and replace operation, e.g. using Perl. Indeed, a one-liner gets the job done:

```
perl -i -0pe "s/^\s*\S*\s*<artifactID>nginx-node<\/artifactID>\s*\S*\s*$//gm" input.txt
```

[Online Regex Demo](https://regex101.com/r/qnb3aO/1) (see regex explanation on the right hand)

Explanation of the flags:

- `-i` tells Perl to perform an in-place replacement, i.e. updates the input file immediately. (Omit this option for a dry-run)
- `-0` turns Perl into "file slurp" mode, i.e. the entire input file is read in at one instead of line by line. This enables multi-line search and replace.
- `-pe` enables to run Perl code directly, in our case pattern matching and replacement.

If you want to find and replace in more than one files, you couple it with `find` and `xargs`, e.g.

```
find ~/mystuff -name "*.txt" | xargs perl -i -0pe 's/regex/replacement/g'
```