# Delete lines by multiple patterns in specific range of lines

Tags: awk, sed

I have the following (simplified) file:

```
 <RESULTS>
  <ROW>
    <COLUMN NAME="TITLE">title 1</COLUMN>
    <COLUMN NAME="VERSION">1,3</COLUMN>
  </ROW>
  <ROW>
    <COLUMN NAME="TITLE">title 1</COLUMN>
    <COLUMN NAME="VERSION">1,1</COLUMN>
  </ROW>
  <ROW>
    <COLUMN NAME="TITLE">title 1</COLUMN>
    <COLUMN NAME="VERSION">1,2</COLUMN>
  </ROW>
</RESULTS>
```

What I am trying to achieve is to delete all ROW elements that match on the title, but do not match on the latest VERSION (in this case 1,3).
So, what I have in mind is something like the following with sed:

```
sed -i '/<ROW>/,/<\/ROW>/<COLUMN NAME=\"TITLE\">title 1.*<COLUMN NAME=\"VERSION\">^1,3<\/COLUMN>/d' file
```

The expected output should be the following:

```
<RESULTS>
<ROW>
  <COLUMN NAME="TITLE">title 1</COLUMN>
  <COLUMN NAME="VERSION">1,3</COLUMN>
</ROW>
</RESULTS>
```

Unfortunately, this did not work, neither did anything that I tried. I searched a lot for similar issues, but nothing worked for me.
Is there a way of achieving it with any Linux command line utility (sed, awk, etc)?

Thanks a lot in advance.

Comment: Is using a proper xml tool an option? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15461737/how-to-execute-xpath-one-liners-from-shell

Comment: Seriously, try XPath: http://xpather.com/nERPMhls.

Answer (score 2):

`/<ROW>/,/<\/ROW>/` won't work, because sed uses greedy matching; it matches everything from the first `/<ROW>/` to the  last `/<\/ROW>/`.

You'll have to use one of the advanced features of sed. The simplest is probably the hold space.

This:

```
sed -n '/<ROW>/{h;d;};H;`
```

will store an entire `ROW` block in the hold space, and overwrite it when it encounters a new `ROW` block. (And print nothing.)

This:

```
sed -n '/<ROW>/{h;d;};H;/<\/ROW>/{g;p;}
```

will store the entire `ROW` block, then print it out when it is complete.

This:

```
sed -n '/<ROW>/{h;d;};H;/<\/ROW>/{g;/title 1/!d;p;}'
```

will do the same, but will delete a block that does *not* contain "title 1".

This:

```
sed -n '/<ROW>/{h;d;};H;/<\/ROW>/{g;/title 1/!d;/1,3/p;}'
```

will do the same, but print only if the block contains "1,3". (You can spell out the matching lines more explicitly; I'm trying to keep this code concise.)

Comment: Could you please explain more about `{h;d;};H;` and `{g;/title 1/!d;p;}'`?

Comment: @ThanLUONG: `/<ROW>/{h;d;}` means *"if it contains ROW, put this line in the hold space (overwriting whatever was there), then delete the line (and begin again with the next line)".* `/title 1/!d` means *"if it doesn't contain 'title 1', delete it (and begin again with the next line)".*

Answer (score 2):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed '/<ROW>/{:a;N;/<\/ROW>/!ba;/TITLE.*title 1/!b;/VERSION.*1,3/b;d}' file
```

Gather up lines between `<ROW>` and `</ROW>`.

If the lines collected don't contain the correct title, bail out.

If the lines collected do contain the correct version bail out.

Otherwise delete the lines  collected.