# Get title of an RSS feed with bash

Tags: bash, shell, terminal, rss

How can I get the title of an RSS feed with Bash? Say I want to get the most recent article from MacRumors. Their RSS feed link is `http://feeds.macrumors.com/MacRumors-All`. How can I get the most recent article title with Bash?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An alternative to xmllint is xmlstarlet and so:

```
curl -s http://feeds.macrumors.com/MacRumors-All |  xmlstarlet sel -t -m "/rss/channel/item[1]" -v "title"
```

Use the xmlstarlet sel command to select the xpath we are looking for and then use -v to display a specific element.

Answer (score 0):

You can combine `curl` and an XPath expression (here, using `xmllint`), and rely on the fact that the feed is in reverse chronological order:

```
curl http://feeds.macrumors.com/MacRumors-All | xmllint --xpath '/rss/channel/item[1]/title/text()' -
```

See [How to execute XPath one-liners from shell?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15461737/how-to-execute-xpath-one-liners-from-shell) for other ways to evaluate XPath.

In particular, if you have an older `xmllint` without `--xpath`, you may be able to use the technique suggested by [this wrapper](https://github.com/sputnick-dev/xmllint/blob/master/xmllint):

```
echo 'cat /rss/channel/item[1]/title/text()' | xmllint --shell <(curl http://feeds.macrumors.com/MacRumors-All)
```

Comment: This gives me the following error (pasted in pastebin): https://pastebin.com/Yk3GKFwA

I'm using macOS

Comment: @twlscnds Add a `-` at the end so `xmllint` knows to read from STDIN. Rewritting the first command: `curl http://feeds.macrumors.com/MacRumors-All | xmllint --xpath '/rss/channel/item[1]/title/text()' -`