# XML document has elements with same name

Tags: c#, xml

I have to work with XML documents that have elements with same name but at different levels. For example:

```
<root>
    <Conceptos>
        <Concepto>
            <Impuestos>
                <Trasladados>
                    attributes and values here...
                </Trasladados>
                <Retenciones>
                    attributes and values here...
                </Retenciones>
            </Impuestos>
        </Concepto>
    </Conceptos>

    <Impuestos>
        <Retenciones>
            attributes and values here...
        </Retenciones>
        <Trasladados>
            attributes and values here...
        </Trasladados>
    </Impuestos>
</root>
```

As you can see, the name **Impuestos** is repeated twice but at different levels. They do not mean the same. Sometimes I have to work with **root>Conceptos>Concepto>Impuestos** and sometimes with **root>Impuestos**. The same happens with the elements **Retenciones** and **Trasladados**.

I am currently testing the **GetElementByTagName** method to get the **Impuestos** element and it returns a list with 2 items. I can see that the **ParentNode** property provides a way to distinguish between them and maybe I can use it.

I can think of writing a method and pass a path to it, something like this:

```
public string GetMyElementValue(string path)
{
    ....Code here....
}
```

An call it something like this:

```
string result = GetMyElementValue("root>Conceptos>Concepto>Impuestos...")
```

Of course, my code would need to contain the logic to somehow "parse" the XML document based on the method path parameter. However, it seems to me this is kind of complicated.

I will very much appreciate your feedback on an optimal way to perform this task.

Best regards.

Comment: Use an xpath to find the element? You'll have to be more specific: What are language are you working in (is that Java or C++)? What XML-parsing library are you using?

Comment: I am using C#, the .NET framework version 8 and its XML support classes.

Comment: I am reading about XPath and it seems this is precisely what I need. I did not know about it since I rarely work with the XML format. I will try it.

Answer (score 0):

Using Xml Linq in Powershell you can do it in stages.

```
using assembly System.Xml.Linq 

$filename = 'c:\temp\test.xml'

$xDoc = [System.Xml.Linq.XDocument]::Load($filename)

$root = $xDoc.Root

$conceptos = $root.Element('Conceptos')
$impuestos = $root.Element('Impuestos')

$conceptosImpuestos = $conceptos.Descendants('Impuestos')[0]
```

Answer (score 0):

Navigating such documents using XPath is pretty much straightforward.
You just give the engine one of these two XPath expressions and it returns the list of exactly those nodes:

```
/Conceptos/Concepto/Impuestos
/Conceptos/Impuestos
```

See also

- [How to execute XPath one-liners from shell?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15461737/how-to-execute-xpath-one-liners-from-shell)
- https://www.saxonica.com/html/documentation12/about/installationdotnet.html